# is it right to use just classes or just IDs in CSS file? will this work?

Tags: html, css

In my CSS lectures, I have been taught that IDs are unique and classes are not.
So I know we can use IDs only once in whole file and classes can be used again.But my question is, during an interview I had been asked What happens if I use only IDs for the whole CSS file? Will it make any difference or we can do that. I was really confused.
Mostly I use classes for the whole thing and it works properly. But I really don't know much how it will work with IDs. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Use class for css. Use id for Javascript/Jquery bindings if events are not common

Comment: It's simple you work in the right way ... you must avoid ID if you can to style since are unique the use can be used more for specificity in strong cases ...

Comment: Too many questions asked, impossible to tell what the real question is and what exactly it is. “Will this work” is just about as vague as you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8kmc7pw/)

```
<div class="div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="div" id="div2"></div>
<div class="div" id="div3"></div>
<div class="div" id="div4"></div>
<div class="div" id="div5"></div>

.div
{
 width: 30px;height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid;
 margin: 2px;
}
#div1.div
{
 background-color: red;
}
```

Here, Size and width are same for all the divs. I can simply use class. Or else it would be `#div1,#div2,#div3{}` . What happen if you add a new div? You must add new div's id in css file.

if you want to set diferent color for different divs, u can use id as i mentioned. Similarly you can use in javascrip/jquery events, if you want to perform different functions on clicking each div.

Comment: +1, boils it all down in one simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDs and the CSS will work, but it's not proper technique. It's a misuse of the purpose of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. But if you want to only use ids, every element must have one. This will be very unstructured. It's recommended to use classes and elements.

Like `div.wrapper > ul > li > a` to select all a tags un the ul list.

For this markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href""></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main drawback IMHO of using only IDs directly in the CSS is that you can't possibly distinguish category of elements in the sense sets of elements that share the same style properties.

This lack of categorisation support would lead to the introduction of redundancy.
This is an open gate towards inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer classes over ids usually to avoid conflicts ,but you have to make a balance between the approaches. Moreover if certain elements can be grouped together for css then it makes sense to have classes but if you want to do something with a particular element then  we use ids.You might also fall into problems in-case your js is used on a different site when you use id's because of conflicts but there are ways to avoid that.So crux is,  go with classes as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

The real reason you don't want to use IDs is not technical, it's, like most things, a people problem.

When you have to work in a large team with a lot of people you don't want conflicts between the ID the javascript guy used and the ID the CSS guy used.

You can have multiple classes, on the other hand, which makes it less conflict-prone.

Also, use namespaces for your classes, style-classes, js-classes, etc.